# Which is the correct H* tag for a nested <section>

Tags: html, article, accessibility

My goal is to use the correct H* tag (H1 to H6) in my html5 code.

I read [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/html5-article-section/) I shouldn't use `<section>` at all: "Why you should choose article over section : Browsers’ visual display of headings nested inside  elements makes it look as if they are assigning a logical hierarchy to those headings. However, this is purely visual and is not communicated to assistive technologies"

but I feel that isn't true because of the answers to [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734350/html5-structure-article-section-and-div-usage?noredirect=1&lq=1): 
that says "sections in an article are like chapters in a book, articles in a section are like poems in a volume" and I want to use sections for their intended purpose.

The problem is [this mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines) says "Important: There are no implementations of the proposed outline algorithm in web browsers nor assistive technology; it was never part of a final W3C specification. Therefore the outline algorithm should not be used to convey document structure to users. Authors are advised to use heading rank (h1-h6) to convey document structure."

The guy from the [first link I posted](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/html5-article-section/) does make a good point about halfway down that page where he says "browsers display different sizes of font depending on how deeply the  is nested in `<section>`s”.

So am I correct in saying I have to correctly match H* tags to depth/nesting to achieve a good outline AND visual styling or is there a different way. eg this would be incorrect:

```
<body>
<h1> something </h1>
<section>
<h1> section heading for outline </h1>
<article>
<h1>my first news article</h1>
<p>stuff</p>
</article>
</section>
</body>
```

because screen readers can't properly process `<section>` for outlining.
and because browsers display different fonts according to level of nesting.
so then would this would be correct?

```
<body>
<h1> something </h1>
<section>
<h2> section heading for outline </h2>
<article>
<h3>my first news article</h3>
<p>stuff</p>
</article>
</section>
</body>
```

note: This is my first question I'm posting so please go easy on me if I've made a faux-pas, I'm new here :)

Comment: The general recommendation is to have a single H1 tag, and the second option is better (semantic-wise) IMO

Answer (score 1):

The document outline algorithm based on `<h1>` has been removed from the spec and actually never worked. In terms of heading levels, your last code example is the correct one.

- [Why the HTML Outlining Algorithm was removed from the spec – the truth will shock you!](https://brucelawson.co.uk/2022/why-the-html-outlining-algorithm-was-removed-from-the-spec-the-truth-will-shock-you/)
- [There Is No Document Outline Algorithm](https://adrianroselli.com/2016/08/there-is-no-document-outline-algorithm.html#Update10)

So you should not use it, and your quote holds true.

> Authors are advised to use heading rank (h1-h6) to convey document structure.

### Correctly using `<section>`

As to the question of using `<section>` vs `<article>`.

You shouldn’t avoid the latter due to styling issues. You already did your research and should stick to your outcome. You’d need to apply some styling yourself, though.

I’d also like to add the ARIA perspective on a page summary:

`<article>` has [role `article`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#article)

> An article is not a navigational landmark

and

`<section>` has [role `region`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#region), which is …

> […] sufficiently important that users will likely want to be able to navigate to the section easily and to have it listed in a summary of the page.

To do so, it is also noted

> Authors MUST give each element with role region a brief label

So, let’s put it together

```html
<body>
<h1> something </h1>
<section aria-labelledby="s1-heading">
<h2 id="s1-heading"> section heading for outline </h2>
<article>
<h3>my first news article</h3>
<p>stuff</p>
</article>
</section>
</body>
```