# What to name div tags that "group" content left and right

Tags: html, css

I have read some of the articles about semantic HTML code, and I am trying to fix my page applying those principles.

I have a index page that contains a section with a welcome greeting, a quick registration form and a big iphone image.

I want the welcome greeting and quick registration to be on the left side (underneath eachother) while the iphone image is on the right side. Now, I wonder how I should float these divs correctly?

I thought of making a left and right div that has the floating property, but the names are not good I think. I also thought of content and sidebar as two grouping div names...but is it really a sidebar? I could need some help.

```
<div id="welcomegreeting">
    <h2>Title</h2>

</div>

<div id="quickregistration">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <form>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>

<div id="appshowcase">
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

*I know the markup is not valid, but it is just for you can see what I mean.*

Comment: Name it what you want. It doesn't matter if you really think it is a sidebar or not.

Comment: Not? What about the semantic=

Comment: As long as it has some semblance to what it does (purely so you remember it better), you can call it sidebar, menu, left-menu, right-menu, or anything. It wastes too much time if you give the decision as much weight as you might give to the name of your website! That's one reason we sometimes have naming conventions, so we don't have to think so much about what it should be named.

Answer (score 3):

> I want the welcome greeting and quick registration to be on the left
>   side (underneath eachother) while the iphone image is on the right
>   side. Now, I wonder how I should float these divs correctly?

```
<div style="float: left;"></div>

<div style="float: right;"></div>
```

The question about naming isn't really relevant. Give it whatever name you want.

If you already have a site, don't worry about removing/changing your divs. You can wrap them with semantic tags.

For information, see [HTML5 best practices; section/header/aside/article elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-tags).

The use of semantic tags isn't going to help your users. However, it might help bots (such as a search engine).

Comment: You're absolutely right. People mostly give these main page `div`isions an identifiers like `#left`, `#right`, `#middle`, `#top`, `#bottom`, `#footer`, `#main`, `#left_menu`, `#top_menu`, `#content`, `#reg_form`, etc etc, so such an important div should have some understoodable name. Classes are used for styling repeating elements. There exists many variants, if you feel that the `div#name` is comprehendious, then it's ok. :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't get caught up too much on it. Semantic code, although the way forward, should be there to help you, not confuse you.

Personally from what you've described, I'd use something like this:

```
<section>
    <div class="welcomeTitle">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="registerForm">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <form>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
<aside>
    <div id="appImage">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
</aside>​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also combine float and margin attributes:

HTML:

```html
<div id="leftside">

<div id="welcomegreeting">
    <h2>Welcome</h2>
</div>

<div id="quickregistration">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <form>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>

</div>

<div id="appshowcase">
    <img src="" />
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
#leftside {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}

#appshowcase {
    margin-left: 202px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWgbn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the left and the right sides in tags with id `left` and `right`, and use the float property. You can name them whatever you want, but you can keep it as simple as left and right. Semantic markup does not mean you have to spend hours deliberating what to call it, it just means that the name should relate as closely as possible to the element's function.

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chc7y/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">
    <div id="welcomegreeting">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="quickregistration">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <form>
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="right">
    Some content
    <div id="appshowcase">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

​
**CSS**

```
#left {
    float: left;
}
#right {
    float: right;
}
```