# HTML tags for an article listing page

Tags: css, html

I have a FAQ page which lists the FAQ topics. It looks something like this:

---

Page heading

page intro

Heading (as a link - ahref) to FAQ topic 1 below
FAQ topic 1 intro text

Heading (as a link - href) to FAQ topic 2 below
FAQ topic 2 intro text

Heading (as a link - href) to FAQ topic 3 below
FAQ topic 3 intro text

..............
..............

---

I wish to use HTML5 to markup this in the most semantic correct way.

Currently I am considering putting it this way:

```
section

   header
      h1 - page header 
      p - page intro
   header end

   div
      article
         h1 a - FAQ topic 1 heading (as a link)
         p - FAQ topic 1 text
      article end
      article
         h1 a - FAQ topic 2 heading (as a link)
         p - FAQ topic 2 text
      article end
      article
         h1 a - FAQ topic 3 heading (as a link)
         p - FAQ topic 3 text
      article end 
      ...........
      ...........
   div end

section end
```

What do you guys think about this markup for the specified scenario? What alternative way could I have resolved this?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: i dont know why you would do this, but you could blast up the articles with stuff in context of each question or in general

Comment: @john I am sorry...I didn't understand what you meant. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your markup is absolutely fine. Just ensure you run it through the W3C validator once its done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find [this page](http://html5doctor.com/outlines/) useful as it lists a number of situations and how to outline the page's content correctly. In your case I can't see any significant semantic issues with your markup.

Edit: I'll also include [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-tags) that includes a good example of a typical page's markup.