# Confusion between <article> or <section> tags. Which to use?

Tags: html, article

Despite reading pages upon pages about the `<article>` and `<section>` tags I really don't understand how to apply them to my site.

I have a product page with related products at the end of the page. First I thought about doing something like this:

```
<section>
   <header><h1>Product title</h1><header>
   <img src="image.jpg"/>
   <p>Description</p>
   <p>Price</p>
   <p><a href="...">Order</a></p>
</section>

<section>
  <header><h1>Related products</h1></header>
  <article>
    <a href="..."><img src="image1.jpg"><br/>Product 1</a><br/>Price
  </article>
  <article>
    <a href="..."><img src="image2.jpg"><br/>Product 2</a><br/>Price
  </article>
  <article>
    <a href="..."><img src="image3.jpg"><br/>Product 3</a><br/>Price
  </article>
</section>
```

But, then I read some other blogs and it occured to me that maybe I should replace the `<section>` tags with `<article>` tags.

Which is right and why? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 best practices; section/header/aside/article tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-tags)

Answer (score 4):

`<article>` is for an independent piece of content that should make sense even if all of it's surrounding content is stripped away. `<section>` is more of a generic container that's quite similar to div tag and mostly used for content structuring. So the right code should be like this:

```
<article>
   <header><h1>Product title</h1><header>
   <img src="image.jpg"/>
   <p>Description</p>
   <p>Price</p>
   <p><a href="...">Order</a></p>
</article>

<article>
  <header><h1>Related products</h1></header>
  <section>
    <a href="..."><img src="image1.jpg"><br/>Product 1</a><br/>Price
  </section>
  <section>
    <a href="..."><img src="image2.jpg"><br/>Product 2</a><br/>Price
  </section>
  <section>
    <a href="..."><img src="image3.jpg"><br/>Product 3</a><br/>Price
  </section>
</article>
```

Also HTML 5 doctor's got a great [Flowchart](http://html5doctor.com/downloads/h5d-sectioning-flowchart.pdf) if you get confused picking the right HTML5 semantic element for your need. You can give it a try and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

**Section**

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content. The theme of each section should be identified, typically by including a heading (h1-h6 element) as a child of the section element.

**Article**

> The article element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.
>
> When article elements are nested, the inner article elements represent articles that are in principle related to the contents of the outer article. For instance, a blog entry on a site that accepts user-submitted comments could represent the comments as article elements nested within the article element for the blog entry.

Straight from the W3 http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html

---

In their example, they have an `article` nested within a `section` within an `article`. I would say you are definitely using it correctly.

```
<article>
 <header></header>
 <section>
  <h1></h1>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
 </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML5 standard, the `<"article">` element defines a complete, self-contained block of related elements.

The `<"section">` element is defined as a block of related elements.

Can we use the definitions to decide how to nest elements? No, we cannot!

On the Internet, you will find HTML pages with `<"section">` elements containing `<"article">` elements, and `<"article">` elements containing `<"sections">` elements.

You will also find pages with `<"section">` elements containing `<section>` elements, and `<article>` elements containing `<"article">` elements.

Right From : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp