# Semantic HTML ARTICLES within SECTION

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I've been reading a lot about Semantic HTML lately and I've been looking at examples at MDN and www.w3.org. However I can not find an explicit answer to this:

Is it semantically correct to have a section with articles as content?

Something along the lines of this:

```
<section>
  <h2>Latest Posts</h2>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
  <article></article>
</section>
```

Closest I've found to that structure is what Morten Rand did at his site: https://mor10.com/ But he's not wrapping the articles with a section but a main tag instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use <section> and <article> tags in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26883406/1591669) -- If yes, I’d suggest to mark it as duplicate

Comment: @unor the answer to that question definitely answers mine, but I don't know wether to mark mine as a duplicate or not, as the question itself is different.

He seems to be asking a more generic question about Articles and Section and I was looking for an specific use case. I feel this question could help other people looking for this, as it's a more explicit question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, you can

A `<section>` element simply represents a generic section of the page. A section on the page can most definitely contain an `<article>`.

[This page](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/) talks about the `<article>` tag, but it does discuss using it inside of a `<section>` element, confirming this:

> Where appropriate a `<section>` element can contain `<article>` elements.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I've been looking for! I'll wait a little bit before accepting your answer, just in case someone else comes with something superelaborated. But that source you gave... it's gold for me.