# Can an aside element have only img inside it?

Tags: html

I'm developing a template using HTML5, and I want to align an `aside` on the left and a `section` on the right.

First question: Can I have only `img`s inside a `header` tag?

Second question: Can I have only `img`s inside an `aside` tag, or is the `aside` tag useless and I should switch to `figure`?

If this is all wrong, how should I organize this piece of code?

```
<header>
    <img id="logo" src="css/images/logo.png" alt="logotipo">
    <img id="slider" class="slider" src="css/images/slide_1.png" alt="logotipo">
</header>

<aside class="left float">           
    <img class="icon" src="css/images/icon.jpg" alt="licone">Name<br>   
    <img class="icon" src="css/images/icon.jpg" alt="licone">adress<br>   
    <img class="icon" src="css/images/icon.jpg" alt="licone">email<br>   
    <img class="icon" src="css/images/icon.jpg" alt="licone">phone<br> 
</aside>


<section class="right float">
    <article>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Is like can i assign an `img` inside `div`, you say Yes. You can assign/wrap how ever you want to. Tags are just for presentation not for which element to wrap in which tag.

Comment: You'll probably be interested in the W3C wiki pages for [the `<aside>` element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/aside) and [the `<header>` element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/header). TLDR is that you can have any content in both of them, as they only define the *semantics* of the type of content.

Comment: Are you asking if your example is valid (i.e., is it valid to have nothing else than `img` as children), or are you asking if it MUST not containg anything else than `img`? You accepted [user3237539’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21612359/1591669) and it seems he/she is answering it in the latter way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First question: Can I have only have `<img>` elements inside `<header>` tags?

No. See the [W3C specification section for `<header>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element). It allows [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1), but doesn't allow `<header>`, `<footer>` or `<main>` descendants.

> Second question: Can i have only img inside aside tag, or this aside
>   tag is useless and i should switch to figure

No. See the [W3C specification section for `<aside>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element).  It allows [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1), but doesn't allow `<main>` descendants.

> If this is all wrong, how should I organize this piece of code?

It's not wrong, and you can organise it however you like - tags such as `<aside>` merely *describe your intent* as to what content is encapsulated inside of them.

If you have some content which you'd like to slightly separate from the main content on a page (while still being related content), use an `<aside>` etc.

Also, you may want to take a look at this - [HTML5 best practices; section/header/aside/article tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-tags).

Comment: Kind of nit picky over the term "documentation", but I'd consider the wiki just references, and the [W3C sections spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html) the actual documentation for these elements.

Comment: The header <img> s ins't related to main content as they are just a logo and a slider and think it's appropriate to wrap into a div.
The <aside> is related to the main content but i want to float left. it's more appropriate use <section>?

Comment: @Johnytota Nope - <aside> is fine, see my update. The <div> in the header won't matter at all.

Answer (score -1):

> Can I have only imgs inside a header tag?

not only img tags, you can have other tags too inside **header** element;
please see: [the list of HTML5 elemnts that can be nested inside header elemen](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/header/html5_header_tag_nested.php)t

> Can I have only imgs inside an aside tag?

not only img tags, you can have other tags too inside **aside** element;
please see: [the list of HTML5 elements that can be nested inside aside element](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/aside/html5_aside_tag_nested.php)

Comment: Instead of posting duplicate answers, you should upvote the original one. This answer only adds noise and is a re-worded version of my answer!