# Do Html5 elements Aside & Nav need a header?

Tags: html

I've been looking for a straight answer to this simple question for a while.

Do Aside & Nav need a header? Obviously if they don't, they will appear in the outline as being without, but is this deemed ok practice?

Comment: If you have time look at the answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-tags/6527766#6527766

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have read the article previously and there is no clarity in it with regard to the question i'm asking.

Comment: The spec defines it as “a group of introductory or navigational aids”. You can use a header in any section on your site. In fact, you probably should use a header within most of your sections. The spec describes the section element as “a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.” This part answers your question..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5 drafts, there is no requirement or recommendation that a `nav` or `aside` element shall or should have a heading. Neither is there any prohibition against headings in them.

What is “ok practice” is really a matter of opinions, with no solid basis to judge it on. The outline algorithm is rather theoretical and has got little attention from browser vendors or search engine vendors. It may be useful as authoring and maintenance tool, or an algorithm used by such tools.