# Structuring HTML5 content - listView, header, footer and menu - with semantic tags

Tags: html, semantic-markup

HTML5 has a variety of new section elements. These elements can be somewhat confusing. I have seen that there are actually very differing opinions on this subject. I've always faithfully followed [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_migration.asp) and I'm sure that this website leads the way but in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-tags?rq=1) popular question HTLM5 tags are used differently. Now, I don't really know which path to follow.

Let me clearify what I'm asking, please consider the following layout:

1. Is it correct to use the `<section>` tag for all the list items? I would use it for grouping together thematically-related content. If yes, should I use the `<header>` or the `h1` tag for the title of the list item?
2. Is it correct to use the `<aside>` tag inside of the section? The content within the aside tag can be removed without reducing the meaning of the main content.
3. Should I use `<section>` (with `<header>` and `<nav>`inside of it) for the Header of the page. Or directly the `<header>` tag as follows?

   ```
   <header>
       <div>Logo here</div>    
       <h1>Name of Website</h1>

      <nav>
        <ul>
           <li>menu 1</li>
           <li>menu 2</li>
           <li>menu 3</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>
   ```
4. The footer part should be a `<footer>` tag as w3schools did in the [example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_html5_skeleton)?
5. Can I use more than one `<nav>` tag in a page, is it convenient from a SEO point of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not wrong. `<article>` is slightly better, but list semantics and a heading (`h[1-6]`) element will be more useful to everyone and probably suffices.
2. Yes.
3. Directly use `<header>`. You sample markup is fine, except that your `<nav>` section appears to contain no links.
4. Yes.
5. You can. I can't comment on SEO.

Warning. W3Schools is not a good web site and the page on the sectioning elements is typically clueless. While their pages can sometimes provide an easy to follow introduction to a subject, treat nothing you read there as gospel.

Comment: 1- Maybe the article tag is better for each single event page.