# Place <aside> next to <p>

Tags: html, css

I need to place  with some motto next to paragraph in article.

HTML code like:

Comment: You don't need `display: block` when you use float.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 best practices; section/header/aside/article elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simply solution is move the `aside` to the top, just next to the img like this:

```
<section>
  <header>..</header>
  <img ..>
  <aside>...</aside>
  <article>
    <p> ..</p>
    <p> ..</p>
    <p> ..</p>
  </article> 
</section>
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/wa0Lcad3/

If you need `aside` appears in the middle of the paragraphs, you should move it into them.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your images and it appears it is a matter of the order of your elements.  You should place your  tag above the  block to keep it above the running paragraphs.

If you want to force the top position you can use

```
position:absolute; 
right:0;
margin: auto;
```

you can use a negative or positive margin of the top to push the element up or down keeping it relative to the placement in the DOM.  This would be to avoid fixed pixel positioning.

Comment: Thank you for tip about position using margin. Very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<section>
<header>..</header>
<img ..>
<aside>...</aside>
<p> ..</p>
<p> ..</p>
<p> ..</p>
</section>

Css for this

section
{
   white-space: normal;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}

img
{
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 24px;
 }

 aside
 {
   float: right;
   padding-left: 10px;
 }
```