# When should I use <article> and <section> from the semantic point of view?

Tags: html, css

I don't understand it. Should I put `<article>` inside `<section>` or should I put `<section>` inside `<article>`. When should I use those? I searched about this topic and found some answers but unfortunately I didn't understand. All they say is that  is used to identify a section of independent, self-contained content that may be independently distributed or reused. But what is actually **"Independent, Self-contained content the may be independently distributed**"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 best practices; section/header/aside/article tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-tags)

Comment: Already covered in detail elsewhere in SO.

Comment: Did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 0):

### HTML5 `<section>` Element

The  element defines a section in a document.

According to W3C's HTML5 documentation: "A section is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading."

A Web site's home page could be split into sections for introduction, content, and contact information.

**Example**

```
<section>
  <h1>WWF</h1>
  <p>The World Wide Fund for Nature (WWF) is....</p>
</section>
```

### HTML5 `<article>` Element

The  element specifies independent, self-contained content.

An article should make sense on its own, and it should be possible to read it independently from the rest of the web site.

Examples of where an  element can be used:

- Forum post
- Blog post
- Newspaper article

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element