# What is the best way to use section

Tags: html

i am wondering what which way is better. I looked at the following answers [HTML5 best practices; section/header/aside/article elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-elements) but can't find it. Someone a idea?

a)

```
<article>
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <section>
    <p>content</p>
  </section>

  <h2>Title 1.1</h2>
  <section>
     <p>content</p>
  </section>
 </article>
```

b)

```
<article>
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <section>
    <p>content</p>
    <h2>Title 1.1</h2>
    <section>
      <p>content</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</article>
```

Maybe there is even a better way?

Comment: `section` is a semantic element. Its use case depends on your design patterns and preference. As long as your consistent and it works for you, it doesn't really matter

Comment: Neither. A good rule of thumb is that each section and article should contain a `<h?>` element that introduces that section/article. So you  should only have `<article><h1>Title 1</h1> <p>content</p><section><h2>Title 1.1</h2> <p>content</p></section></article>`